# I Am Looking For A Formula That Randomizes My Numbers Until They Sum Within A Range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently I am trying to change old data into random data that is on one sheet onto another sheet. So it sort of looks like this:

On my first sheet Titled "NUMBERS INPUT" I have all of the data in cells B2:O97

On my other sheet titled "NUMBERS GENERATED" I have:
=RANDBETWEEN(0 , 'NUMBERS INPUT'!B2)
Which goes all the way to O97

What I want is something like this that runs to numbers until they are "random enough" to be within a range like:
=SUM(B2:O97)=MIN(180:261)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Screenshot of Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRyIk.png)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a sort of work around that give's me the result I want. Kind of.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16-5o_8Q18sYPFoHPP74LxrWfd5LWyAE6VyJrp2Ei8uI/edit?usp=sharing

Check it out.